# What's the best method to graph the following function by hand...

Tags: functions, absolute-value

Here in my exercise I have to study the function and draw its graph. Can you please tell me what's the best method to do this, because I don't think that's reasonable to use the input output method, it's quite imprecise.
$$f(x)={|x+1|\over x}$$

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way.

- First, draw the graph of $\frac{x + 1}{x}$.
  This should be pretty simple since $\frac{x + 1}{x} = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$, and you know what $\frac{1}{x}$ looks like.  You also know that $\frac{x+1}{x}$ has a zero at $x = -1$.
- Second, since $|x + 1|$ switches the sign for $x < -1$, take the graph you just drew and reflect the portion with $x < -1$ across the $x$-axis.  Keep the portion with $x > -1$ the same as it was before.

Answer (score 3):

- There is a zero at $x = -1$.
- The function does not exist at $0$ and grows infinitely large near $0$.
- The function is positive when $x  > 0$ and negative when $x < 0$.
- When the function hits the $x$-axis at $x = -1$ it is a sharp corner rather than a smooth bump, since the absolute value function changes abruptly.
- As $x \to \infty$, the function approaches $1$ from above.
- As $x \to -\infty$, the function approaches $-1$ from above.

Along with a few plotted points, this should give you enough information to draw a precise graph.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to break the mod into cases when $x>-1$ and...

Let me talk of case : $\frac{x+1}{x}=1+\frac 1 x$

$1/x $ is odd function. It tends to infinity at $0^+$ and tends to $0$ at infinity.

Make graph of $\frac 1 x $ and shift it one unit upward. Erase all part left of $x=-1$. Can you do the same for other part?

**PS:** : The best method is to plot using one of many graphical calculators available and then copy them in you notebook of course, **by hand**.

Comment: So do I have to make the graph of $1\over x$ by inserting respective values of $x$ and then calculating $y$, traditionally?

Comment: 1/x graph is pretty basic.

Comment: Using automatic tools to solve the problem for you when you have to study to solve such problems is not only not the best method, it's in fact the worst.

Comment: @Ruslan It isn't.